# Where to begin with IPv6

Tags: ipv6, network-design

I am fairly familiar with setting-up IPv4 networks for bigger server configurations, only now I wanted to start familiarizing myself with doing the same for IPv6.

I have been Googling for the second night in a row for things like: IPv6 network design, IPv6 for dummies, etc. So far most things you find go on about why IPv6 and the amazing amount of numbers that we have now.

Yet I am looking for practical stuff, for example:

1. what would be a good way to assign IP-number, as I understand it DHCP shouldn't be the default course of action.
2. How do other assignment methods work with DNS configuration?
3. what would be a good or standard way of dividing the network in to sub-nets? (database, application, web servers spread over multiple domains/applications and some what intertwined)

In short I would like to find good resources with practical information books, webpages, etc. Does anyone have any resources that worked for them?

Comment: Get out and do it would be my suggestion. fire up some virtual machines and have at it.

Comment: You might include "best practices" in the search pattern for IPv6.

Comment: Thx,both! will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly too broad a question for us to address, but there are some resources you can probably use.

To start, check out [ARIN's IPv6 wiki](http://www.getipv6.info/), especially [Book Reviews](http://www.getipv6.info/index.php/Book_Reviews) and [Educating Yourself about IPv6](http://www.getipv6.info/index.php/Educating_Yourself_about_IPv6).

Keep in mind that some books will be extremely out of date; IPv6 has evolved quite a bit since it was first introduced in the late 1990s. I'd recommend accepting nothing older than [O'Reilly's IPv6 Essentials](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100582) (2006) (and double checking everything you see in there, too).

Comment: thanks! I will check O'reilly's and the pages you suggest!